# How to sync Map <-> MySQL in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, hashmap, synchronization

I got a HashMap and a MySQL Database.
Whenever my programm starts, it reads everything from the database and saves it into the HashMap.
Now I need to save everything back into the Database when I close my programm or every X seconds/minutes.

I was running into several problems:
- It's not 1:1 if I do SQL INSERT only. Do I have to compare everything (probably takes too much time)?
- Deleting everything in the database before saving the HashMap would be bad too.

Comment: When you read into the hashmap include a variable than indicates the given item has been loaded. Then when you come to save, only save the items that do not have the variable set, this could be the id value from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Personal opinion would be perform save or update.

Maintain a dirty flag for each map item. set it's value while reading the map, if it require any update or insert and perform save and update only on that item.

For each map item first check if its dirty flag and perform save or update operation accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. Using a dirty flag now.